# Page break in dmath equation environment

Tags: math-mode, page-breaking

I have a very very long equation. I want it to split over different pages automatically. My quation contains 1700 terms and it may go for many pages. Is it possible with dmath or any other way?

e.g.,

```
\begin{dmath}
a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b
+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c
+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d
+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e
+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f
+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a
+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b
+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c
+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d
+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e
+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f
+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a
+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b
+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c
+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d
+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e
+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f
+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a
+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b
+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c
+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d
+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e
+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f
+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a
+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b
+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c
+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d
+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e
+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f
+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a
+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b
+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c
+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d
+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e
+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f
+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a
+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b
+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c
+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d
+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e
+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f
+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a
+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b
+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c
+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d
+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e
+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f
+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a
+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b
+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c
+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d
+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e
+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f
+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a
+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b
+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c
+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d
+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e
+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f
+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a
+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b
+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c
+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d
+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e
+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f+a+b+c+d+e+f
\end{dmath}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: (My first reaction is to wonder if this posting is a delayed April Fool's joke.) Please post a more realistic example. Incidentally, have you considered the `multline` environment of the `amsmath` package?

Answer (score 5):

You don't want `dmath`, but simply

```
\begin{quote}\raggedright
$<long and unreadable formula>$
\end{quote}
```

You might want to turn this into a personal environment:

```
\newenvironment{longformula}
  {\begin{quote}\raggedright$}
  {$\end{quote}}
```

so you just need to type

```
\begin{longformula}
<long and unreadable formula>
\end{longformula}
```

Example from the file you show in the comments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{quote}\raggedright
$(\nabla \cdot S4)_1=\alpha_{1} \mathrm{u} \frac{\partial^{3}}{\partial x\partial^{2} y}
\mathrm{u} + \alpha_{1} \mathrm{v} \frac{\partial^{3}}{\partial^{3} y} \mathrm{u} +
3 \alpha_{1} \frac{\partial \mathrm{u}}{\partial x} \frac{\partial^{2}
\mathrm{u}}{\partial^{2} y} + 4 \alpha_{1} \frac{\partial \mathrm{u}}{\partial y}
\frac{\partial^{2} \mathrm{u}}{\partial x\partial y} + \alpha_{1} \frac{\partial
\mathrm{u}}{\partial y} \frac{\partial^{2} \mathrm{v}}{\partial^{2} y} + 2 \alpha_{1}
\frac{\partial \mathrm{v}}{\partial y} \frac{\partial^{2} \mathrm{u}}{\partial^{2} y} + 2
\alpha_{2} \frac{\partial \mathrm{u}}{\partial x} \frac{\partial^{2}
[...]
\mathrm{v}}{\partial y}\right)^{2} \frac{\partial^{2} \mathrm{v}}{\partial^{2} y} + 8
\gamma_{8} \left(\frac{\partial \mathrm{v}}{\partial y}\right)^{3} \frac{\partial^{2}
\mathrm{u}}{\partial^{2} y} + \mu \frac{\partial^{2} \mathrm{u}}{\partial^{2} y}$
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

I replaced `\operatorname` (which is wrong in this context) with `\mathrm` throughout.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for giving me the suggestion. The actual tex file containing my equation is availble here (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8PyWlc7uQ8RbFBGU0FkakZLZEE/edit?usp=sharing) and the output i got inserting entire equation in $< enite code>$ is available here (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8PyWlc7uQ8RNkpUYk5wWVlpOHM/edit?usp=sharing). In this code line beaking is not proper, how break lines with proper alignement.

Comment: @PriyadarsanKP Add `\raggedright` between `\begin{quote}` and `$`; also replace `\operatorname`, which is wrong here, with `\mathrm`.